# Problem understanding the conceptual solution to a deformable system problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

A particle is suspended from a post on top of a cart by a light string of length L as shown in (a). The cart and particle are initially moving to the right at some constant speed, with the string vertical. The cart suddenly comes to rest when it runs into and sticks to a bumper as shown in (b). The suspended particle then swings through an angle θ. If the bumper is still exerting a horizontal force on the cart when the hanging particle is at its maximum angle forward from the vertical, at what moment does the bumper stop exerting a horizontal force?

[image]

According to the book, the bumper stops applying a force when the particle swings back to its lowest point. This leftward force is necessary to reverse the rightward motion of the particle and accelerate it to the left. However, I'm having trouble understanding why would the bumper keep exerting a force even after the particle has reached its maximum angle? I just don't see how that's possible. Wouldn't the bumper stop exerting a force the moment the total momentum of the cart+particle system becomes zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why would the bumper keep exerting a force even after the particle has
> reached its maximum angle?

Because the tension in the thread still pulls the cart to the right.

Comment: Follow-up question: why did the author state that the force exerted by the bumper is necessary to accelerate the particle to the left? Doesn't the force of gravity the one responsible for accelerating the particle to the left while the tension in the string is simply there to constrain the particle's motion in a circular path?

Comment: @Niko : "Doesn't the force of gravity the one responsible for accelerating the particle to the left"? I am not sure. On the one hand, if there were no gravity, the particle would not accelerate to the left, on the other hand, gravity does not provide acceleration in the horizontal plane. If there were no string, there would be no acceleration to the left.

Comment: @Niko :  "why did the author state that the force exerted by the bumper is necessary to accelerate the particle to the left?" Again, I am not sure. I believe if there were no bumper (after the particle had moved to the right), the particle would still accelerate to the left, although with a lesser acceleration (due to the movement of the cart).

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it now. As you have said, the tension in the string pulls the cart to the right which in turn causes the bumper to exert a reactive force in the opposite direction. As long as the tension is directed at an angle, there will always be a horizontal component that pulls the cart to the right. Therefore, the bumper will stop exerting a force if the tension has no horizontal component, which is true when the particle is at its lowest point.